# What regex would I use to add javadocs to a java program in vscode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, javadoc, find-replace

My current attempt:
Find: `(^$\n[\s]*.*\{|^$\n[\s]*.*@.*$)`
Replace: `/***/$1`

Problem: works well except for the fact that the javadoc boilerplate is not indented.

What change would I implement to indent it accurately?

---

Input:

```java
public class Main {

    class innerClass {

        int a;
        int b;

        @Override
        private int goo() {

        }
    }

    String a;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // blablabla
    }

    @Override
    public int foo(int a) {

    }
}
```

output:

```java
/***/
public class Main {
/***/
    class innerClass {

        int a;
        int b;
/***/
        @Override
        private int goo() {

        }
    }

    String a;
/***/
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // blablabla
    }
/***/
    @Override
    public int foo(int a) {

    }
}
```

---

Expected output:

```java
/***/
public class Main {
    /***/
    class innerClass {

        int a;
        int b;
        /***/
        @Override
        private int goo() {

        }
    }

    String a;
    /***/
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // blablabla
    }
    /***/
    @Override
    public int foo(int a) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not an extension?

Comment: The built-in one requires me to do a Ctrl+. on every function name and even then it does not work for ones with annotations :(...
Oh, and no third party extensions are permitted

Comment: Format on save?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this regex

```
^([\s\n]*(^\s*)[^{};]*\{)
```

And replace it with

```
$2/***/$1
```

What it does is essentially finding all `{}` blocks without encountering a field(statements end with `;`) and put the same length of indent within the same line of the open curly bracket and a `/***/` before it.

You may see the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/olo07V/1)

Comment: any way I can add a new line after the javadoc boiler plate?

Comment: Yes, replace it with `$2/***/\n$1` lol

Comment: because this is what I came up with: `(^$\n([\s]*)(.*\{)|(@.*)$)` and it works perfectly fine except for annotations where it works like your code.

Comment: nope, the javadoc gets added below the annotation

Comment: Does your annotation contain `{`, `}` or `;`? What does the failed case look like?

Comment: failed test case: https://imgur.com/a/WDA9pkE

Comment: I think I found the problem now, in VSCode `\s` does not contain line break `\n`, so you need to add it to the set `[\s\n]`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Got ya! Will try this shortly :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @HaoWu's really clever block capturing, the following works too!
Find: `(^$\n([\s]*)(.*\{$|[\s]*@.*)$)`
Replace: `$2/***/$1`

Comment: FYI the square brackets in `[\s]*` is unnecessary, since it only contains one type of character set.